# How to make all numbers go to two decimal places in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display a float with two decimal places in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149006/display-a-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-python)

How can I force all numbers in python to output two decimal places after them?

E.G.

0.5 should be 0.50

Comment: (Please close duplicates as duplicates - absolutely nothing new or exciting here.)

Answer (score 7):

The [format mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) is preferred these days (since the `%` format operator [may be deprecated one day.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)):

```
>>> print '{:.2f}'.format(.5)
0.50
```

Plus, IMHO, string.format() is easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

```
>> print '%.2f' % 0.5
0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

To print numbers:

```
print "%.2f" %num
```

To store numbers in variables:

```
round(num, 2)
```

Comment: `round(num,2)` rounds the number which has more than 2 decimal places to 2 decimal places but cannot make a number with 1 decimal place into 2. It cannot make 0.5 into 0.50

Comment: fair point. I didn't know whether OP was asking for printing or for program internal representation. This is why I gave both solutions