# How to add zeros after the decimal to make 2 digits after decimal in ipython and pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I have a list of numbers in `ipython` through `pyspark` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(N))
df['total'] = data.map(lambda x:(x.features[0]+x.features[1]+x.features[2])).collect()
```

Now some of the numbers in this list come out to have two digits after decimal like `10.17` but there are numbers which have less than two digits after decimal like `9.1` or some do not have any decimal like `5` or `23`. What I want is to have all the numbers two digits after decimal. If they do not have two digits then an ending 0 should be added like for above `9.1` should become `9.10` and `5` should become `5.00`. How can I do that?

**NOTE:** I have seen posts that do that reformatting but my reformatting is in respect to the `pyspark` and the `map()` function specifically. How do I do the reformatting there?

Comment: And they have to be stored as floats?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display a float with two decimal places in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149006/display-a-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-python)

Comment: @Tim I saw that post but how do I do that here with data.map() statement. I don't care about them storing in this format. All I want is to display them.

Comment: What does it mean _display them_? If you need fixed precision numbers you should use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). If you simply want specific output you can map to strings with specific format.

Answer (score 0):

The display doesn't happen in the map lambda function. The values are materialized when collect() returns your array of results. You'd then apply formatting to those results.