# How to save last 0 in decimal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For web automation testing i am generating randint and convert it into % and inputing it into fields, and then checks that value appears correctly.

```
install_share = randint(1000, 9999) / 100
        install_share = str(install_share)
        install_share = install_share + "%"
```

the problem is, if random value will have 0 as it last symbol, then after devision it will loss last '0' after decimal

```
a = 1970 / 100
print (a) # 19.7, but i need 19.70
```

I've tried

```
a = 1970.00 / 100
print (a) # 19.7

a = float(1970) / float(100)
print (a) # 19.7
```

but each time i received same rounding.

Comment: @CoryKramer: I think the OP might be looking for this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149006/display-a-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-python

Comment: That is another good link, thanks for adding it.

Comment: @CoryKramer, thanks

Comment: @l'L'l, thanks for link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 1970/10 # a = 19.7
print("{:.02f}".format(a))
>>> 19.70
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what i was needed.