# Pandas formatting number to strange format (like Excel does for big numbers)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a json file that contains an attribute like `"registration":1540558108796.0`. When pandas read, it converts the number to `1.54056e+12`

I've tried to set dtypes:

```
df = pd.read_json(filepath, dtype={'registration': object}, lines=True)
```

But still printing same value `1.54056e+12`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41328899/5124383) is a good answer to this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['registration']=df['registration'].astype('int64')
```

Try This one

```
 df['registration']=df.registration.map(lambda x: '{:.3f}'.format(x))
```

Comment: It truncates the number and returns 1540558108796, when original is 1540558108796.0. If you try with a number like 1540558108796.36, it returns 1540558108796. It's not a good solution.

Comment: Try 2nd option in above answer. you can replace 3f with any number.