# Suppress scientific notation in to_markdown() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a number of questions about suppressing scientific notation in Pandas in general

- [Format / Suppress Scientific Notation from Python Pandas Aggregation Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results)
- [Suppressing scientific notation in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas)
- [How do I print entire number in Python from describe() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328633/how-do-i-print-entire-number-in-python-from-describe-function)

However, none of them seems to apply to the `to_markdown` function. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': 3e10}, index=[0])  # print(df) gives 3.000000e+10
pd.set_option('float_format', '{:f}'.format) # print(df) gives 30000000000.000000
```

However, `df.to_markdown()` still yields

```
|    |   val |
|---:|------:|
|  0 | 3e+10 |
```

How can I disable the scientific notation in `to_markdown()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out the answer during writing the question.

`df.to_markdown()` [uses tabulate](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8588651d8479d6ef908114480e54900b6020d700/pandas/core/frame.py#L2501) under the hood. We can thus use the `floatfmt` parameter mentioned in the [tabulate readme](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) to disable the formatting:

### `print(df.to_markdown(floatfmt=''))`

yields

```
|    |           val |
|---:|--------------:|
|  0 | 30000000000.0 |
```

as @oneextrafact notes in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891971/1785661), you can use `floatfmt='.0f'` to control the number of decimal places shown.

Answer (score 4):

To build on @dahn's answer, if you don't want the decimal point use this format string:

```
print(df.to_markdown(floatfmt='.0f'))
```