# remove e-log values in pd.describe()

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a df where when I see its head(), I see values like this:

```
id val
1  24228
```

However, when I check df.describe(), I see values in a scientific notation. Can this be avoided to see values in full decimal values?

```
           val
mean       7.302745e+04
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328633/how-do-i-print-entire-number-in-python-from-describe-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with the [display.float_format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) to suit what you need. Maybe something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.4f' % x)
```