# How to keep decimal places with two zeros?

Tags: python-3.x

Using the lib `Decimal` i can set the `quantize` to get the 2 decimal places with zero:

```
from decimal import Decimal
value = Decimal('1000.0').quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
print(value) # Decimal('1000.00')
```

But if i need to change it to `float` the last zero disappear:

```
value = float(value)
print(value) # 1000.0
```

**How can i set two zeros at decimal place and still use as float?**

the `print` method was an e example to show the final result, i need to use the `value` as `float` and not `string`.

the value will be used in a json request:

```
{
    "value": 1000.00
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a float with two decimal places in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149006/display-a-float-with-two-decimal-places-in-python)

Comment: @Cray my question is how to get the value as float with two zeros on decimal places and not how to convert it to string, i need that the final value should be float with two zeros and not a string

Comment: If you want to print it with two decimal places, don't convert it to float. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Do you need two decimal places of precision?

Comment: @wjandrea i'm consuming an API and this api is having trouble to interpret this `1000.0`, they say that i need to send as `1000.00` (json)

Comment: @Rafa I just saw your comment above. What you're asking for (float `__str__`/`__repr__` showing two decimal places) is not possible, unless you subclass `float` or convert it to a string. Please make a [mcve] and explain exactly what you need.

Comment: OK, just saw your edit. Yes, you actually do want to convert it to a string. Though I'm not sure how exactly to convert that into json. Maybe this? [Format floats with standard json module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447287/4518341)  Edit: actually I'm not sure - sorry, I have little experience in this.

Comment: Actually, you do not care if it is `1000` or `1000.00` in a json, because this is the same thing